# Plotting android recording samples's amplitude on moving graph RealTime

Tags: android, audio, graph, audio-recording, mpandroidchart

I'm developing a recording app, for which I am trying plot amplitude of audio recording samples against time on Android View similar to below image.

The graph should move with time towards the left side of the screen.

[image]

I tried using LineChart of MPChart Library but still, the result is not as expected.

MPChart homepage has a screenshot of such graph, but couldn't figure it how to implement.

Please help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use LineChart for that, here is official `RealtimeLineChartActivity`:

**[Oficial RealtimeLineChartActivity example](https://github.com/crashlytics/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartExample/src/com/xxmassdeveloper/mpchartexample/RealtimeLineChartActivity.java)**

Like in the sample, you should feed (`feedMultiple` method) it with data from other Thread, periodically (Runnable)

Hope that helps